# SQL Server filtered index - can anyone explain this error I am seeing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, so I have a table with a filtered index.  Here is a script to create the table, add some data and then add the index:

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier (
    SupplierId INT NOT NULL,
    SupplierLinkId INT NULL,
    SupplierName VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO Supplier VALUES (1, 2, 'Test Supplier 1');
INSERT INTO Supplier VALUES (2, NULL, 'Test Supplier 2');
INSERT INTO Supplier VALUES (3, NULL, 'Test Supplier 3');
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uq$Supplier$SupplierLinkId ON Supplier (SupplierLinkId)     WHERE SupplierLinkId IS NOT NULL;
```

Then I decide I want to add a new column, say for a Supplier Code, to my table and for maintainability reasons I don't want it to be at the end of the table.  So I can't use:

```
ALTER TABLE Supplier ADD SupplierCode VARCHAR(50);
```

Instead I go into the table designer, I highligh the SupplierLinkId column and right-click, insert column and enter the details:

- Column Name = SupplierCode;
- Data Type = VARCHAR(50);
- Allow Nulls =

When I click Save I get this error:

'Supplier' table
- Unable to create index 'uq$Supplier$SupplierLinkId'.
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Supplier' and the index name 'uq$Supplier$SupplierLinkId'. The duplicate key value is ().
The statement has been terminated.

But this index is supposed to be filtered, for some reason it is ignoring the filter.

If I try to drop the index:

```
DROP INDEX Supplier.uq$Supplier$SupplierLinkId;
```

...and go back to my still open table designer I get this error instead:

Table 'Supplier' has changed:
- Index 'uq$Supplier$SupplierLinkId' was deleted and will be recreated.

So I have to come all the way out of the designer and then go back in to make the change.  Then I can recreate my index (that shouldn't have been a problem in the first place).

But then I decide I want the new Supplier Code column to be non-nullable so I go and change it in the designer... and get the same error about the index having duplicate values.  Instead I have do script this job with:

```
ALTER TABLE Supplier ALTER COLUMN SupplierCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
```

Now I can understand that the table designer might not like it if changes are made to the table while it is open and that is quite understandable.  What I don't understand is why I can't use the table designer to make changes to my table without getting a spurious error about my filtered index having duplicate values when it clearly doesn't.

Comment: A suggestion: stop using the designers. They're really bad.

Comment: It seems to be bug in designer - if you check Change Script you will see that filtering part of the index is omitted. You might check [this blog](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2013/03/sql-server-table-designer-bug-with.html) for details.

Comment: If you can get out of the habit of wanting columns in particular positions, you'll have an easier life too.

Comment: Okay, I figured I would get some flack for caring about column order.  It isn't a "bad habit"; there are plenty of good reasons to care about order.  One example that springs to mind is some financials databases that I work with that have very, very large tables.  One has a rule that columns appear in strict alphabetical order.  This just makes life easier when working with these big tables.  Another example is grouping items that "belong" together just to make life easier when performing a straight "SELECT *" from that table.

Comment: Thanks Nikola, I checked that blog and it looks like this has been fixed for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Using `SELECT *` is in itself also a [bad habit you might want to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), so is not really a reason to care about column order. If you explicitly list the columns you want as you should (and MSDN also [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190238.aspx)), then column order should be inconsequential. There are a few debates about performance impact, but I have not seen any tests to prove this yet, so I'm sitting on the fence with regard to performance.

Comment: SQL Server does not support adding or re-ordering columns, period, as column output in a relational table is only related to the order of requested output.  It is bad practice to imagine otherwise as it allows institutions to create weird and unsupported business rules :)

Answer (score 0):

I also like to reorder new database columns for readability to help those poor future devs & dbas that come after me. After all, in mature applications 40% - 90% of time spent will be rework and changing requirements.

However, Microsoft doesn't agree, so there is no column reordering SQL but you can vote for it on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124781/alter-table-syntax-for-changing-column-order) if you like wasting your time. They prefer that you use temp tables and recreate your table, like below...

```
--rename table to free up the name
EXEC sp_rename 'Supplier', 'Supplier_backup'
GO

--create the table again with the new column in the order that you like
CREATE TABLE Supplier (
    SupplierId INT NOT NULL,
    SupplierCode VARCHAR(50),
    SupplierLinkId INT NULL,
    SupplierName VARCHAR(50))
GO

--copy the data back in 
INSERT INTO Supplier (SupplierId,SupplierCode,SupplierLinkId,SupplierName)
SELECT SupplierId,NULL,SupplierLinkId,SupplierName
FROM Supplier_backup
GO

--add the index
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uq$Supplier$SupplierLinkId ON Supplier (SupplierLinkId)     
WHERE SupplierLinkId IS NOT NULL
GO

--cleanup the old table
DROP TABLE Supplier_backup
GO
```